# UPDATE temporary table using subquery and joined table fails

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, mysql-error-1054

I have an appraisal_lines table in my database and want to take some data from the first appraisal and display it alongside the same data from the latest appraisal so progression from the first to the current appraisal can easily be seen.  I am doing this with three values from both appraisals plus other data from the current appraisal.

To do this I think I need to create temporary table to hold both sets of fields plus the additional fields from the current appraisal.

My temporary table is created as follows:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE appraisal_lines_submitted (
    current_perceived_state INT(2),
    current_actual_state INT(2),
    current_desired_state INT(2),
    agreed_action_points TEXT,
    agreed_actions_target_date DATE,
    assessor_notes TEXT,
    category_id INT(2),
    sub_categories_id INT(2),
    sub_categories_description VARCHAR(45),
    sequence_number INT(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    first_perceived_state INT(2),
    first_actual_state INT(2),
    first_desired_state INT(2)
);
```

I then run an insert and select statement as follows to put the data from the current appraisal into the temporary table:

```
INSERT INTO appraisal_lines_submitted (
    current_perceived_state,
    current_actual_state,
    current_desired_state,
    agreed_action_points,
    agreed_actions_target_date,
    assessor_notes,
    category_id,
    sub_categories_id,
    sub_categories_description,
    sequence_number)
SELECT appraisal_lines.perceived_state,
    appraisal_lines.actual_state,
    appraisal_lines.desired_state,
    appraisal_lines.agreed_action_points,
    DATE_FORMAT (appraisal_lines.agreed_actions_target_date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS agreed_actions_target_date_formatted,
    appraisal_lines.assessor_notes,
    appraisal_lines.assessment_category_id,
    assessment_sub_categories.id,
    assessment_sub_categories.description,
    assessment_sub_categories.sequence_number
FROM appraisal_lines LEFT JOIN assessment_sub_categories
    ON appraisal_lines.assessment_sub_category_id = assessment_sub_categories.id
WHERE hyperlink_token ='db678f8595edcd78d8ea7f055f7ee790b804c91e'
    AND assessment_category_id ='5'
ORDER BY sequence_number;
```

This works OK.

However when I run the update statement below it fails

```
UPDATE appraisal_lines_submitted JOIN
    (SELECT appraisal_lines.perceived_state as update_perceived_state
     FROM appraisal_lines
     WHERE hyperlink_token ='d7cc7e1adc116e0dac31cbad34cd9a2b322c3507'
        AND assessment_category_id ='5'
     ORDER BY appraisal_lines.assessment_sub_category_id
    ) AS increments 
    ON increments.update_perceived_state = appraisal_lines.perceived_state
    SET appraisal_lines_submitted.first_perceived_state = update_perceived_state;
```

with the error

> Error Code: 1054
>   Unknown column 'appraisal_lines.perceived_state' in 'on clause'

I wrote the update statement based on the post : [MySQL Update a field value with subquery with multiple returning rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413436/mysql-update-a-field-value-with-subquery-with-multiple-returning-rows)

Answer (score 3):

Here's your script with some bits highlighted in bold:

```
UPDATE appraisal_lines_submitted JOIN
    (SELECT appraisal_lines.perceived_state as update_perceived_state
     FROM appraisal_lines
     WHERE hyperlink_token ='d7cc7e1adc116e0dac31cbad34cd9a2b322c3507'
        AND assessment_category_id ='5'
     ORDER BY appraisal_lines.assessment_sub_category_id
    ) AS increments 
    ON increments.update_perceived_state = appraisal_lines.perceived_state
    SET appraisal_lines_submitted.first_perceived_state = update_perceived_state;
```

Now, in your script you are joining a table named `appraisal_lines_submitted` to a (derived) table named `increments`. The joining condition references a column from `increments` and a column from... wait a minute, `appraisal_lines`? What is that? There's no table by that name among those taking part in the join.

My guess is, the `appraisal_lines.perceived_state` reference in the joining condition should be replaced by `appraisal_lines_submitted.current_perceived_state`.

My other guess is, you missed `LIMIT 1` after `ORDER BY`, which is based on the name of the column being updated (`first_perceived_state`)

Comment: Thanks Andriy
It looks like it was the = appraisal_lines.perceived_state which I have removed but now each row in the temporary table is updated with the result from the first row of the SELECT statement.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: @Mike: I'm afraid I can't help you there. Well, not until you elaborate on how it should be.

Comment: Thanks with the suggestion from Tony re correlated subqueries I was able to get it working, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The parser cannot see the table `appraisal_lines` because you are updating `appraisal_lines_submitted`.

The only place you specify the `appraisal_lines` in within the inner `SELECT` which is aliased as `increments`

You can also drop the `ORDER BY` in the inner `SELECT`, the join will be performed irrespective of the ordering of the inner data.

Comment: Thanks Tony
Have made progress but inner select query returns multiple rows in this case 6 rows but this will vary depending on the value put into assessment_category_id.  The temp table is updated once per row, again in this case 6 rows are updated but the update is using the first row result in each row.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: @Mike - it sounds like you need to modify the Correlated Subquery (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) to link the inner rows to the outer ones. What is the Primary Key of `appraisal_lines` and how does it relate to `appraisal_lines_submitted`? You already use `increments.update_perceived_state = appraisal_lines.perceived_state` to link them but which other field would ensure only one inner row updates the outer?

Comment: thanks I changed it to SET appraisal_lines_submitted.first_perceived_state = update_perceived_state WHERE sub_categories_id = increments.assessment_sub_category_id and it works now. Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: For all, final statement below

Comment: UPDATE appraisal_lines_submitted JOIN
    (SELECT perceived_state as update_perceived_state, assessment_sub_category_id
     FROM appraisal_lines
     WHERE hyperlink_token ='d7cc7e1adc116e0dac31cbad34cd9a2b322c3507'
        AND assessment_category_id ='1'
    ) AS increments 
    ON increments.update_perceived_state
    SET appraisal_lines_submitted.first_perceived_state = update_perceived_state WHERE sub_categories_id = increments.assessment_sub_category_id;